# Why do I need to have this IF statement in my function?

Tags: javascript

So basically I just need clarity on why I need to use the if statement in the code... I understand why the other code needs to be there but currently learning right now.

```
const todos = [{
    text: 'Order cat food',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'Clean kitchen',
    completed: false 
}, { 
    text: 'Buy food',
    completed: true 
}, {
    text: 'Do work',
    completed: false 
}, {
    text: 'exercise',
    completed: true 
}]

const deleteTodo = function (todos, todoText){ 
    const index = todos.findIndex(function (todo){
        return todo.text.toLowerCase() === todoText.toLowerCase()
    })
    if (index > -1) {
        todos.splice(index, 1)
    }
}

deleteTodo(todos, 'Buy food') 
console.log(todos)
```

Comment: _You_ need to tell _us_ why that `if` statement is there, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

This line `if (index > -1) {` is checking the index of the element in the array. If this element is present in the array it will return a number 0 or greater than 0. `-1` mean the element is not present in the array. Invariably it is also checking if the element is present in the array.

So if the element is present in the array then `splice` is applied and it will return the `removed` item.

Answer (score 0):

Array.findIndex returns -1 if the item is not in the array, doing a splice with an index of -1 will cause an error.

Comment: It will not throw error but it will remove last item in an array.

Answer (score 0):

`deleteTodo` function will remove an item from todo's list based on the `text` provided to it. If the passed `text` does not exists then we shouldn't perform `splice` on the todo's array.

Note that `findIndex` will return array index starting from `0` to `length-1` if text is present in array else `-1`.

Ex:-

```
deleteTodo('eat food');
```

The above should not alter array since `eat food` text is not found in `todos` array.

Consider if you are performing splice for above statement then it would result in

```
todos.splice(-1,1)
```

which will remove the last item in `todos` array since `-`(minus) indicates index from end of an array.